# 'Freezing' Arrays in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, freeze

Since the ECMA-262 specifications Javascript has gained the *Object.freeze()* method, which allows for objects, whose properties can not be changed, added or removed.

```
var obj = {'a':1, 'b:2'};
Object.freeze(obj);
Object.isFrozen(obj);       // returns true
obj.a = 10;                 // new assignment has no affect
obj.a;                      // returns 1
```

So far so good.

I am wondering, whether freeze() should also work on Arrays.

```
var arr = [1, 2];
Object.freeze(arr);
Object.isFrozen(arr);      // returns true
arr[0] = 10;
arr;                       // returns [10, 2] ... ouch!
```

Maybe I am wrong, but I was under the impression, that Array inherits from Object.

```
typeof obj                 // "object"
typeof arr                 // "object"
```

Any ideas, pointers, enlightenments would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I *would* expect it to freeze the array as well. Which browser(s) exhibit(s) said behavior?

Comment: Doesn't work in FF6: `var a = []; Object.freeze(a); a.push('foo'); // TypeError: a.push("foo") is not extensible`

Comment: It looks like it's an implementation bug. 'Freezing arrays' works in Firefox (6.0.2), Chrome (14.0.835.186) - but not on the previous version. It does not work on Safari (5.1).

Comment: @trembl: it won't work on browsers that were created before the new standard rolled out.

Comment: @salman-a Which is why it's funny, that it does not work in Safari 5.1 (release date: 20 July, 2011), and neither in the latest Webkit nightly ( Version 5.1 (6534.50, r95673) ). I am only curious why Chrome, which is also build onto of Webkit doesn't suffer from this... Maybe because of the V8 Javascript engine?

Comment: Just tried the array example in Chrome today, the output is `[1, 2]` and NOT `[10, 2]`. Looks like the array accessor doesn't throw an error, but it works.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Yes, freeze should work for Arrays, the behavior you are experiencing is clearly an implementation bug.

This bug might be related to the fact that array objects implement a custom [`[[DefineOwnProperty]]`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.5.1) internal method (the magic that makes the `length` property work).

I just tested it on two implementations and it works properly (Chrome 16.0.888, and Firefox Aurora 8.02a).

About your second question, well, array objects inherit from `Array.prototype` which inherits from `Object.prototype`, for example, you can access non shadowed methods from `Object.prototype` directly on array objects:

```
['a'].hasOwnProperty('0'); // true
```

But this isn't related about how the `typeof` works, this operator will return `'object'` for any object intance, regardless its kind, and for the `null` value, which people has always complained about.

The rest of possible return values of the `typeof` operator, correspond to the primitive types of the language, Number, String, Boolean, Symbol and Undefined.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, it is applicable to arrays too.

```
const arr = [1,2,3,4];
Object.freeze(arr);
Object.isFrozen(arr)// true
arr.push(5) // you will get a type error
arr.pop() // you will get a type error
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a situation where I wanted to use a key as a reference, and still return the key.

I wanted `PERMISSION` to be a simple array, not an object that has a duplicated key/value. e.g.

```js
const PERMISSION = ['A1','A2','A3'];
```

used in another object like so

```js
export const PERMS = Object.freeze({
    [PERMISSION.A1]: { ... },
    [PERMISSION.A2]: { ... },
});
```

for that to work (and not give `undefined`), I came up with this:

```js
const arr = ["A1", "A2", "A3"];
const PERMISSION = Object.freeze(arr.reduce((ac, a) => ({ ...ac, [a]: a }), {}));

console.log(PERMISSION);
// {'A1':'A1','A2':'A2','A3':'A3'}

console.log(Object.isFrozen(PERMISSION));
// true

console.log(PERMISSION.A1)
// A1
```

A downside is `arr` is still mutable

```js
const arr = ["A1", "A2", "A3"];
arr.push("A4");
console.log(arr);
// ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4']

console.log(arr.A1)
// undefined
```

one solution would be to remove `arr` and put the array directly in the `Object.freeze`

```js
const PERMISSION = Object.freeze([
    "A1", "A2", "A3"
].reduce((ac, a) => ({ ...ac, [a]: a }), {}));
```

not necessarily the best solution, but a solution that makes an array immutable and fit my use case, hopefully it helps someone else who searches the same question.

Answer (score -8):

Instead of freeze, use spread operator to copy things without modifying them (if you are using a transpiler, of course):

```
const second = {
  ...first,
  test: 20
}
```