# Freezing the elements of an array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of certain primitive elements:

```
const array = [1, 2, 3]
```

I want to be able to temporarily **freeze an element of this array** and prevent it from being modified. But the moment the element can be allowed to be modified, there should be a way to unfreeze the value.

Is there a way to do so?

**Off-topic for those who flag this question as duplicate:**

The question is about freezing the elements of an array, not the entire array. It is not a duplicate of a question regarding freezing the entire array.

Comment: Does [`Object.freeze()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze#Description) meet your requirements?

Comment: My thoughts would be to make a custom object that holds the primitive value and a boolean value of locked, if it's locked, don't allow change, if it is not locked, allow change.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['Freezing' Arrays in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509894/freezing-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: Prevent certain values from being modified by whom? A programmer? A user? I'm not sure what the end goal is here. You'd probably want to look at objects.

Comment: @zero298 I tried doing it this way: `const arr = [1, Object.freeze(2), 3]`, it did not work.

Comment: @Leo this is not a duplicate, he doesn't want to freeze the entire array.

Comment: Even if `Object.freeze(2)` would work, what would be the point of "freezing" a constant value? O.o

Comment: @Andreas Only the array definition is constant.  You can still push and pop values of it in JS.  You just can't reassign to `array`, so `array = [5];` will error.

Comment: @zero298 I'm totally aware of that... TO is calling `Object.freeze()` on the number `2` which doesn't make any sense - as explicitly mentioned in my comment...

Comment: @Andreas Oh, my bad, I see what you mean.  Yes I don't know what the purpose of that is.

Comment: @Andreas Nobody ever said it makes sense to do so. I was suggested to try this method. I tried. It did not work. I relayed this information to the advisor. Period.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to freeze the *value*, you want to freeze the *property* that holds the value (the `"1"` property of the array, in your case). You'd use [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to redefine the property without the `writable` flag. To make it writable again, you redefine it with `writable: true`:

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3];
console.log("A", array.join(", ")); // 1, 2, 3

// Freeze it
Object.defineProperty(array, "1", {
  value: array[1],
  writable: false, // For emphasis (this is the default)
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true
});
console.log("B1", array.join(", ")); // 1, 2, 3
array[1] = 42;                       // <== Doesn't change it
console.log("B2", array.join(", ")); // 1, 2, 3 (still)

// Thaw it
Object.defineProperty(array, "1", {
  value: array[1],
  writable: true,
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true
});
console.log("C1", array.join(", ")); // 1, 2, 3
array[1] = 42;                       // <== Changes it
console.log("C2", array.join(", ")); // 1, 42, 3 (changed!)
```

That assignment would be an exception if the code doing the assignment were running in strict mode:

```js
"use strict";
const array = [1, 2, 3];
console.log("A", array.join(", ")); // 1, 2, 3

// Freeze it
Object.defineProperty(array, "1", {
  value: array[1],
  writable: false, // For emphasis (this is the default)
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true
});
console.log("B1", array.join(", ")); // 1, 2, 3
array[1] = 42;                       // <== Doesn't change it
console.log("B2", array.join(", ")); // 1, 2, 3 (still)

// Thaw it
Object.defineProperty(array, "1", {
  value: array[1],
  writable: true,
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true
});
console.log("C1", array.join(", ")); // 1, 2, 3
array[1] = 42;                       // <== Changes it
console.log("C2", array.join(", ")); // 1, 42, 3 (changed!)
```

But note that if *your* code can redefine it to make it writable, anyone else's code can, too.

Alternately, give it a getter and setter, make it non-configurable (so no one else can redefie it), and maintain a flag:

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3];
let elementValue = array[1];
let writable = true;
Object.defineProperty(array, "1", {
  get: function() {
    return elementValue;
  },
  set: function(newValue) {
    if (writable) {
      elementValue = newValue;
    }
  },
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: false // Again, emphasis
});

console.log("A", array.join(", ")); // 1, 2, 3
array[1] = 42;
console.log("B", array.join(", ")); // 1, 42, 3 -- it changed
writable = false;
array[1] = 67;
console.log("C", array.join(", ")); // 1, 42, 3 -- didn't change
writable = true;
array[1] = 94;
console.log("D", array.join(", ")); // 1, 94, 3 -- changed
```

Naturally, you'd hide some of that and just expose the array itself.

Comment: A special "thank you" for elaborating on the terms in the first sentence.